# how to convert json to composite type

Tags: json, postgresql

i'm trying once again to work with postgres 9.4 and the new json functionalities and might have encountered a bug. The Problem is that once i have generated a json-string via to_json(..) i cant transform it back to an Composite type because postgres cant handle the json-array inside.

When i write it in postgres Notation it works and i can even access all the fields inside the Array.

Does anyone knows a better workarround?

Example 1: composite type to json and back
    DROP TYPE IF EXISTS myType;
    CREATE TYPE myType AS (
        since TIMESTAMP,
        words TEXT[]
    );

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    _my_variable myType;
    _my_json JSON;
BEGIN
    _my_variable := ROW(now(),ARRAY['Here','is','a','List','of','Words']);
    _my_json := to_json(_my_variable);

    RAISE INFO 'how my json looks like: %', _my_json;
    --{"since":"2015-06-30T09:12:35.12346","word":["Here","is","a","List","of","Words"]}

    _my_variable := json_populate_record(NULL::myType,_my_json);

    --ERROR:  malformed array literal: "["Here","is","a","List","of","Words"]"
    --DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
    --CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 13 at assignment
END $$;
```

Example 2: json with postgres-notation like array to composite type

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    _my_variable myType;
    _my_json JSON;
BEGIN
    _my_json := '{"since":"2015-06-30T09:12:35.12346","words": "{Here,is,a,List,of,Words}" }';
    _my_variable := json_populate_record(NULL::myType,_my_json);
    RAISE INFO 'how my object looks like: %', _my_variable;
    RAISE INFO 'how my array looks like: %', _my_variable.words;
    --("2015-06-30 09:12:35.12346","{Here,is,a,List,of,Words}")
END $$;
```